# Creating a decode algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I create an algorithm to decode a number (code) and associate it with a specific genre?

For example:

```
0= 1 =zombie

1= 2 =horror

2= 4 =romance

3= 8 =action

4= 16 =medieval
```

This is my genres list. The reason it is set up like this is, say the user enters 3 then what would come out is zombie, horror because 1+2=3.

How do I create a function that will take a code (int value) and return a list of genres that associate with it. If the code is (12) I need the function to return the list L=[4,8].

What I have figured out so far! I know that if the user enters 12 then 12 is less than 16 (the next power of 2) and is the previous 2 genres added together. I just don't know how to translate that into my code.

```
def _decode(self, code):
  codes=[] #need and empty list to add the values to
  #need code that will take the code value and associate it to its respective genres. 
  return codes
```

What i have done so far is this:

```
Def _decode(self, code):

codes=[]

for i in range (0,10):

 i = 2**i

 if i==code:

codes.append(i)
```

What this is doing is, if the user enters 2 and 2 is already a power of 2 and can only be associated with 1 genera it just appends that number to the list codes=[].

What if the user enters a 3? I know that 3 is less then the next power of 2 with is 4 and is the previous 2 numbers added together. How can I split that 3 up into a 1 and a 2 and append both those values into the codes=[] List?

Comment: This doesn't uniquely decode. 4 could be romantic horror or zombie romance.

Comment: It does uniquely decode. Those are powers of 2, so basically bit-flags. romantic horror is 2+4=6

Comment: 0=1 is dangerous. All kinds of math will implode.

Comment: Oh, only the number on the right is supposed to count? I thought it was saying that both `0` and `1` count as zombie, and both `1` and `2` count as horror. That should really be made more clear.

Answer (score 5):

You can list all the genres

```
>>> genres = ['zombie', 'horror', 'romance', 'action', 'medieval']
```

Then make a the mapping of movies by left shifting (`<<`) by the index

```
>>> codes = {1 << index : value for index, value in enumerate(genres)}
>>> codes 
{1: 'zombie', 2: 'horror', 4: 'romance', 8: 'action', 16: 'medieval'}
```

Then use bit-wise AND to find the matching genres

```
>>> user = 7    # which is 1 + 2 + 4, or 0b111
>>> [movie for key,movie in codes.items() if user & key]
['zombie', 'horror', 'romance']
```

You just need to make sure that if you were to bitwise XOR your keys together, you would get back all 1's

Comment: For convenience, you do not need to assign the powers of 2 yourself. You could generate a unique bitmask for every N with `(1 << N)` in the comprehension

Comment: @Felk Good call, edited my post to use bitshifting in a `dict` comprehension to generate the keys.

Answer (score 3):

Shamelessly stolen from Cyber and modified to not use a dictionary:

```
>>> genres = 'zombie', 'horror', 'romance', 'action', 'medieval'
>>> user = 7
>>> [genre for i, genre in enumerate(genres) if user & 2**i]
['zombie', 'horror', 'romance']
```

Comment: I'd use `1<<i` instead of `2**i`, it makes it clearer that this is a bit operation and it should be faster (not that it matters).

Comment: I think more people are familiar with powers than with bit shifts. Though honestly I just couldn't remember whether `<<` has higher preference than `&` :-P

Comment: Good point about precedence, but I often just litter my code with superfluous parentheses and stop worrying about it.